# Scipy zscore stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, statistics

I have a 7,500,000 million row x 6 column dataframe. The dtype output for is:

```
column1                 int64
column2                 int64
column3                 object
column4                 float64
column5                 float64
column6                 float64
dtype: object
```

Column 3 indicates it is a string when I try to change the datatype to float (it is a date) using

```
df.column3.astype(integer)
```

The output is

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float"
```

So to the nitty gritty: I am trying to normalize the data using zscore, and I've used the following:

```
from scipy.stats import zscore
df.apply(zscore)
```

and

```
import statistics
norm_column = (df - df.mean())/df.stdev()
```

I let the first one run for almost two hours, and the second one has been running for about as long. I'm going to let it run for a while, but to me it seems like it shouldn't take so long to run. Is there a chance I messed up my code somewhere, or something is stuck in an infinite loop? Any help would be appreciated, and I will be more than happy to provide more information.

Comment: Suspicious. Aren't you running out of memory?

Comment: I was having that issue initially so I cut down a lot of the data and set up earlyoom (Ubuntu 22.04) for monitoring the memory/swap. The available memory is 50.27% and swap is 50.01% as I type this, and I'm not getting the same issues with running out of RAM as earlier - so I don't thiiinnkkk so

Comment: If you're swapping, you can be sure that the process will take a very, very long time.

Comment: Ah cool thanks for the heads up, I killed the swap and restarted the kernel, hopefully it doesn't take too long

Comment: I have turned swapping off, but it is still taking forever - do you have any other ideas about what it could be?

Comment: If I were you, I'd ditch pandas and process this massive dataframe manually, starting with debugging outputs. For example, it would definitely ease your mind if you saw the current line number being processed.

Comment: Did you really mean "7,500,000 million"?